# Inserting a potentially missing line with perl

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to modify a perl filter to insert a line that may be missing.

I might have inputs that are

A
B
C

or

A
C

A and B are fixed and known in advance. C can vary from file to file.

The real data are more complicated - callstacks generated as part of
a regression test. Depending on the compiler used (and hence the
optimization) there may be tail call elimination which can remove
the 'B' frame. After filtering the files are simply diffed.

In the second case I want to insert the 'B' line. In the first case I don't want to insert a duplicate line. I thought that this was a job for negative lookahead, using the following

```
s/A.(?!B)/A\nB/s;
```

However this seems to mean "if any part of A.(?!B) matches the input text then substitute it with A\nB" whereas I need "if all of A.(?!B) matches" then substitute.

No matter what I try it either always substitutes or never substitutes.

Comment: 1) How big can the file get? 2) Do you mean that a line starting with "B" always comes after a line starting with "A" and before a line starting with "C"?  (If it's there.)

Comment: 1) quite small, mostly about 50 lines and 1-2kbytes. 2) Yes, there will either be A-B-C or A-C. I'll update the question with a bit more info.

Comment: I'll be honest. I needed a quick fix so I hacked something quickly with awk. I will get back to this after my vacation.

Answer (score 6):

In a one-liner for a ready test

```
perl -0777 -wpe's/ ^A.*\n \K (?!B.*\n) /B-line\n/xgm' file
```

The `\K` makes it drop all matches before it, so we don't have to capture and copy them back in the replacement side. With the `-0777` [switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) the whole file is slurped into a string, available in `$_`.

In order to match all such `A-B?-C` groups of lines we need the `/g` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) (match "globally"), and for the anchor `^` to also match on internal newlines we need the `/m` modifier ("multiline").

The `/x` modifier makes it disregard literal spaces (and newlines and comments), what allows for spacing things out for readability.

On the other hand, if a line starting with `A` must be followed by either a line starting with `B`, or by a line starting with `C` if the `B`-line isn't there, then it's simpler, with no need for a lookahead

```
perl -0777 -wpe's/ ^A.*\n \K (^C.*\n) /B-line\n$1/xgm' file
```

Both these work correctly in my (basic) tests.

In either case, the rest of the file is printed as is, so you can use the `-i` switch to change the input file "in-place," if desired, and with `-i.bak` you get a backup as well. So

```
perl -i.bak -0777 -wpe'...' file
```

Or you can dump the output (redirect) into the same file to overwrite it, since the whole file was first read, if this runs out of a script.

---

Reading the file line by line is of course far more flexible.  For example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $just_saw_A_line;

while (<>) { 
    if ($just_saw_A_line and not /^B/) { 
        say "B-line";
    }   

    $just_saw_A_line = /^A/;
    print
}
```

This also handles multiple `A-(B?)-C` line groups. It's far more easily adjusted for variations.

The program acts like a filter, taking either `STDIN` or lines from file(s) given on the command line, and printing lines to `STDOUT`.  The output can then be redirected to a file, but not to the input file itself.  (If the input file need be changed then the code need be modified for that.)

Comment: I forgot to mention initially that I only know A and B in advance, C may vary. I'll try these out tomorrow.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Ah, alright.  (That's why I asked about it under the question.)  If the variations are known (and reasonable) can still use the second form, where you'll then match for those variations (with an alternation perhaps or so).  Update and let me know and I'll update.  Also, I'll add a "normal" solution whereby you process the file line by line.  Far more flexible...

Comment: @PaulFloyd Added a line-by-line example